# Intermediate command-line interfaces

Tags: c, io, ncurses

I've been working with C for a while and am reasonably proficient at simple command-line interfaces. I've also had a play with the `curses` library, for terminal applications that do more than write text to `stdout`. However, I can't figure out where the half-way point is - applications like `wget` or `make` have, for example, the ability to update the text they have output (like `wget`'s bouncing download meter and progress bar), without taking over the entire screen.

Is this sort of interface something I should be using `curses` for, or is there a step in between? Preferably one that is cross-platform.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of wget to see how the download meter/progress bar works? Its open source: you can learn from it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do some simple things by just printing backspace characters `'\b'` and raw carriage returns `'\r'` (without newlines).  Backspaces move the cursor backwards one character, allowing you to overwrite your output, and carriage returns move the cursor back to the start of the current line, allowing you to overwrite the current line.

Here's a simple example of a progress bar:

```
int progress = 0;
while(progress < 100)
{
    // Note the carriage return at the start of the string and the lack of a
    // newline
    printf("\rProgress: %d%%", progress);
    fflush(stdout);

    // Do some work, and compute the new progress (0-100)
    progress = do_some_work();
}
printf("\nDone\n");
```

Note that you should only do this if you're writing to an actual terminal (as opposed to being redirected to a file or pipe).  You can test for that with `if(isatty(fileno(stdout)) { ... }`.  Of course, the same would be true if you were using any other library such as curses or ncurses.

Comment: +1. Checking for `isatty(fileno(stdin))` would be advisable before doing this, btw.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, good point (except you want to test if `stdout` is a terminal, not `stdin`).

Comment: Ehm, `stdout`, yes. Silly me :)

Comment: I'm guessing from all these responses there'll be no truly cross-platform solution (given that `isatty` seems to have been deprecated in CS2005), but thanks for this!

Comment: Your code has interesting issues if the user presses enter, or more importantly if your progress message ever shrinks in length. A more robust solution can be constructed using terminfo.

Comment: @derobert: Yes, that's true.  This is a simple, light-weight solution.  Using terminfo or curses is a better way to go, but they're a lot more work to set up and use.

Answer (score 4):

Between `stdio` and `curses` is the standard Unix/POSIX [`termios`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html) library. Trivial example program that turns character echoing off and reads a line (note, no error checking whatsoever):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void munch_line()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
}

int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct termios tio;

    printf("Enter something: ");
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &tio);
    tio.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &tio);

    munch_line();
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Don't forget to turn echoing back on before exiting the program ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal supports [VT100 escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php), you can use them to move the cursor around:

```
printf("\x1b[%uD", n);  /* move cursor n steps to the left */
printf("\x1b[%uC", n);  /* move cursor n steps to the right */
printf("\x1b[K");       /* clear line from cursor to the right */
printf("\x1b[1K");      /* clear line from cursor to the left */
printf("\x1b[2K");      /* clear entire line */
```

A quick example (`curtest.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("ZZZZZZZZZZ");
    printf("\x1b[%dD", 10U);  /* move cursor 10 steps to the left */
    printf("YYYYYYYYY");
    printf("\x1b[%dD", 9U);   /* move cursor 9 steps to the left */
    printf("XXXXXXXX");
    printf("\x1b[%dD", 2U);   /* move cursor 2 steps to the left */
    printf("\x1b[1K");       /* clear line from cursor to the left */
    printf("\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If your terminal supports these escape codes, it should print

```
mizo@host:~/test> gcc curtest.c 
mizo@host:~/test> ./a.out
       XYZ
mizo@host:~/test>
```

The Windows command line does not have built-in VT100 support.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see something familiar to the topic of these answers. Some of us are using a simple carriage return, as am I.

Consider `xiv` to be an incremental counter, `size_of_pages` the amount of data presented for input or output at a time. They are both uint64_t (somewhat needless). `total` is a `float`. It has the length of the entire IO to read thru.

```
if ((((float)(xiv * size_of_pages)/total)*100) >= xnt)
{
    xnt = 0.01 + (((float)(xiv * size_of_pages)/total)*100);
    printf("\rPercent Done: %.2f%% [", xnt);
    float vbc = 0;
    kp = 0;
    while (vbc < 10)
    {
        if (kp < (xnt)/10) {
            printf("#");
            kp += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf(":");
        }
        vbc++;
    }
    cout << "]" << flush;
    fflush(stdout);
}
```